# Getting button position not working properly

Tags: jquery, css

jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.get-dropdown-menu', function(e) {
    var target = $(this);

    // After getting the HTML content by using ajax set the CSS
    $('class').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': target.offset().top + target.outerHeight(),
        'bottom': 'auto',
        'left': target.offset().left,
        'right': target.offset().right
    });
});
```

HTML code (appendTo body):

```
<div class="dropdown_menu">
    <ul role="menu">
        <li>
            Delete
        </li>   
        <li>
            Report abuse
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the results of the code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSMAw.png

The code is getting the menu position of the button successfully but I need the menu appear like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7EtI.png

I trying to make something like this but it's not wokring:

```
'left': target.offset().left - target.width()
```

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl like now? I think the all important information is added to the question.

Comment: Change it to `target.offset().left - $("class").width()`. You want it to move over the width of the dropdown, not the button element.